# How to make work Yelp (Gnome Help)?

Tags: release-freya, design

Why do some built-in apps have a non-working help menu? It shows nothing when I push on it. In Ubuntu (yelp), gnome help manager works, but in elementary OS Freya it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 2):

elementary OS does not use Yelp. Part of the design philosophy is "[minimal documentation](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#minimal-documentation)". In a nutshell, if it needs documentation it's not a good design.